# How do I disable the Secure Logon background image in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, desktop-customization

At day 1 of the windows 10 release my Secure Logon background was a solid colour, the same colour as my accent colour. Since Windows automatically updated it has been changed to a picture.

How do I get the solid colour back?

To be clear, I want this specifically for the Secure logon screen (where it shows "Press Ctrl-Alt-Delete" to unlock), not the standard logon screen.

Comment: [How to Change the Login Screen Background on Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/223875/how-to-change-the-login-screen-background-on-windows-10/)

Answer (score -1):

There is Registry edit you can do. You can enable or disable windows 10 logon background image, it replaces the image with your default (accent) color.

You can use a zip file from [this HowToGeek Guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/223875/how-to-change-the-login-screen-background-on-windows-10/) ([Direct Link](http://cdn3.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Disable-Logon-Background-Image-on-Windows-10.zip))

For completeness the two reg files are replicated here:

#### `Disable Logon Background Image on Windows 10.reg`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"DisableLogonBackgroundImage"=dword:00000001
```

#### `Enable Logon Background Image on Windows 10.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"DisableLogonBackgroundImage"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: If you are going to use external content (in this case from HowToGeek) then  you should link to the actual page with the content on it, not the direct link.  It would also be good to state how to go about using it or what it will achieve.